# Migrate Chatter Answers to Chatter Questions due to Chatter Answers going to Retire ASAP

Tags: community, chatter, migration, chatter-feed, winter18

We are using the chatter answers in community which is going to retire after Winter 18 release. Wanted some suggestions to perform the migration...below are the research...
Investigated on Q&A Migration App but wanted to know if someone has used this and its outcome. Was there any data impact? If yes, then how can we overcome that?.
What is the alternative? Is data loader an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this guide for steps to be followed in migration - https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150M000003suDYQAY

Salesforce has provided help article for this here which also lists the migration app which is the tool to migrate - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Salesforce&type=1

Limitations ->

While Chatter Questions has several valuable features, there are also several things that it does not have such as:

1.Rich Text Editing is not available for answers to Chatter Questions

2.Outside of Reports and Dashboards, no consolidated list view is available when used internally

3.Differences in custom email alerts and customization options around workflow/ processes

**After Migration->**

When questions from Chatter Answers are migrated to a community,

1.Reply records are converted to FeedComment records

2.Vote records are converted to FeedLike records

3.Question records are converted to FeedItem records

Comment: Thanks for the help.Can you please clear us the below questions.  

1.Currently the community is built using VF Pages and actively use Chatter Answers for discussions ...The task is to reuse the existing community but to migrate Chatter Answers to Chatter Questions. Does the app help to achieve this?  
2.What is volume of data the App can handle? Is there any limitation?  
3.Can this App be install in Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the App is meant to achieve Chatter Answers to Chatter Questions migration. Regarding volume the App has the option to set batch size. Yes it can be installed on Sandboxes. Additionally it is officially confirmed that Chatter Answers will retire in Spring 18 and not in Winter 18 as announced earlier.